# protobuf-net version without system.servicemodel dependency?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Just a quick question - is there a protobuf-net distro without the system.servicemodel and WCF tie-ins? Or i would need to fork on github and compile my own?

It's a headache because i'm trying to use protobuf in a SQL CLR environment (don't ask...) and that *thing* requires the entire reference tree statically registered before it allows any execution - and system.servicemodel fans out to 22 assemblies this way, which understandably does not make DBAs happy, even if none of those 22 actually get loaded.

Oh and it needs to be for .net 3.5 a la SQL Server 2008

Comment: I'm sure Marc Gravell will show up with the definitive answer approx. 2 minutes after I click "Add Comment", but here goes anyway. I'm using the DLL from this path "ProtoBuf-Net-zip\protobuf-net r668\Full\net20" with .Net Framework 3.5 without any problems, and without any dependencies on system.servicemodel or WCF, at least not that I've noticed.

Comment: @RenniePet he did not show up. Did you activate the Marc-Signal?

Comment: It wasn't cloudy last night. Maybe tonight he sees the signal ! @RenniePet +1 for the .net 2.0 suggestion. Should work out for what i'm using, won't be able to refer the nuget directly though :(. So follow up - if i'm installing a nuget in a 3.5 project, anyone knows how to force it to add the 2.0 reference? So i can keep the auto-updates, package restore etc.

Comment: marked as duplicate because they are *essentially* the same; yes, you would have to do a separate build or use the 2.0 stuff manually

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the definitive answer. Do i delete this question? or it stays as-is? Don't know the protocol...