# nuget - Reference specific framework version from installed package?

Tags: nuget, protobuf-net

This scenario goes a bit against the whole way nuget works so what i might be asking for is a hack...

My problem:

I need to have Restsharp and Protobuf-net referred to in a .net assembly that going into SQL-CLR for Server 2008 (so max .net 3.5, framework 2.0).

Restsharp goes back to 3.5 as the lowest supported fwk version.

Protobuf-net 3.5 onwards has a lot of gunk referring to system.servicemodel (and WCF) which i don't need and use and actively want to remove because it causes issues with installing on SQL-CLR. Protobuf-net 2.0 doesn't have this :)

So i've built and tested my code with an assembly targeting .net 3.5 and i installed the restsharp nuget - which gave me the correct reference and i manually added a reference to the protobuf-net 2.0 distro.

This is where i'd like to know - can i (in any way) install the protobuf-net nuget package but still have it reference the .net20 DLL in my assembly which targets 3.5?

The static reference is not a huge deal since protobuf-net has been pretty stable, but i'd like to get the whole setup via nuget if possible.

In the end, this is a workaround as solution to:
[protobuf-net version without system.servicemodel dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571852/protobuf-net-version-without-system-servicemodel-dependency)

If there's a better answer to that, i'd be very grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not possible. You could of course create your own custom build and host it on a local nuget drop, or as your own nuget package on the public feed. AFAIK, there's no way to do what you want inside a new nuget folder in the existing package.

Comment: Ah well, i did the arguably criminal hack of adding a .net 2.0 empty library to my solution and installing the protobuf nuget on it and referencing it via path from there for the 3.5 one. Thanks for the clear not possible though.